# Django AJAX returns undefined instead of the variables

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, ajax, django

So I have a simple Django script which I've found online for an AJAX function that runs a Python script and gets the output via stdout.

***views.py***

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
    return render(request,'homepage/page.html')
```

***homepage/page.html***

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>test</title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function()
            {
                $('#clickme').click(function(){
                    alert('Im going to start processing');
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "static/homepage/js/external_func.py",
                        type: "POST",
                        datatype:"json",
                        data: {'key':'value','key2':'value2'},
                        success: function(response){
                            console.log(response.keys);
                            console.log(response.message);                            
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="clickme"> click me </button>
    </body>
</html>
```

So you can see my url is linked to `external_func.py` which runs after the button is clicked. The script then returns a json.

***external_func.py***

```
import sys
import json
import cgi

fs = cgi.FieldStorage()

sys.stdout.write("Content-Type: application/json")

sys.stdout.write("\n")
sys.stdout.write("\n")


result = {}
result['success'] = True
result['message'] = "The command Completed Successfully"
result['keys'] = ",".join(fs.keys())

d = {}
for k in fs.keys():
    d[k] = fs.getvalue(k)

result['data'] = d

sys.stdout.write(json.dumps(result, indent=1))
sys.stdout.write("\n")

sys.stdout.close()
```

However, when I run the server and clicked on the button, the console shows undefined for both values, meaning `response.keys` and `response.message` is undefined.

[image: Console]

Now, when I instead switch the code to `console.log(response)` in `homepage/page.html`. The console prints out the entire `external_func.py` code in text.

I couldn't find a solution online. It seems like people rarely calls a Python script in an AJAX request, I see a lot of forum posts about AJAX calling for a php code instead.

***EDIT1:***
I have to clarify one thing. This is just a small section of my project which I want to run some test on. In my actual project, I will have a function in python that takes a long time to compute, hence I prefer to have a webpage partially rendered with a waiting icon while the function processes. The output from the function will then be displayed on a webpage.

Comment: You can't deploy a Python or Django application just by putting the `.py` files into a static webserver.

Comment: @KlausD. `external_func.py` as written is a CGI app, not a django app.

Comment: "I prefer to have a webpage partially rendered with a waiting icon while the function processes." - There is no difference serverside between an AJAX view and a non-AJAX view. The only consideration that would favour splitting the function off would be the fact that it will take up a django thread for the duration of execution, which might make other requests wait if your traffic is significant.

Answer (score 1):

You have a django app, and yet you are using CGI for this function? Why? Why not simply make the function another django view? Serving your response with django is much superior to CGI, unless that function significantly bloats or slows down your django. It is as easy as this:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
def func(request):
    result = ...
    return JsonResponse(result)
```

If you really want to separate this into a CGI script, the most likely reason you are failing to get a response is your web server not being configured to process the CGI request. (Your Developer Tools Network tab is a great help for diagnosing exactly what kind of response you got.) For security reasons CGI is not enabled by default. You need to tell Apache (or whatever web server you are using) that CGI should be enabled for that directory, and that it should be associated with `.py` files.

Comment: I'm using this for testing purposes only. In my actual project, I will have a function in python that takes a long time to compute. The output from the function will then be displayed on a webpage.

Comment: Okay. Can you confirm what response you are getting from the server? Either by Developer tools, or by `curl -i url.py`? Also, what is your server's OS, and which web server you're using? (Apache, nginx...?)

Comment: Right now I'm developing on my Windows 8.1 laptop.I'm simply running it via `python manage.py runserver`. When I actually deploy the code, I'll use a Ubuntu server and nginx as my web server.

Comment: Then you do not have a web server capable of running CGI - the mystery is solved. Unless you install a web server, you cannot do this. Django's `runserver` can't run CGI for you.

Comment: Not quite - nginx doesn't support CGI either, AFAIK. I don't have much experience with nginx, but based on a quick Google, it could work with nginx, uWSGI and [its CGI plugin](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/CGI.html). I really think you should just implement it as a django view as described in the answer, then wait to see if the traffic is too heavy till you decide the effort to make this independent is worth it. "Premature optimisation is root of all evil" and all that.